# Azure Functions failed to acquire host lock lease: Azure.Storage.Blobs

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, azure-functions

I have an Azure Function that runs just fine when running it locally. However, when I deploy it to Azure I get the following:

> 2021-08-18T13:54:49Z   [Verbose]   Host instance
> 'cf18298b771b53ee3f905f085f3a7fe0' failed to acquire host lock lease:
> Azure.Storage.Blobs: One of the request inputs is out of range.
> RequestId:7bc9eccb-601e-0060-0f38-9460f3000000
> Time:2021-08-18T13:54:49.2543060Z
>
> Status: 400 (One of the request inputs is out of range.)
>
> ErrorCode: OutOfRangeInput

Any ideas? I can't figure out what the issue might be

EDIT (adding code):

```
public partial class Function
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    private readonly IDataMiner _dataMiner;
    private readonly HealthCheckService _healthCheck;
    private readonly ILogger<Function> _logger;
    private readonly IDatabaseMigrationTool _migrationTool;
    private readonly JobOptions _options;
    private readonly ITeamsNotificationService _notificationService;

    public Function(
        ILogger<Function> logger,
        IConfiguration configuration,
        HealthCheckService healthCheck,
        IOptions<JobOptions> options,
        IDatabaseMigrationTool migrationTool,
        ITeamsNotificationService notificationService,
        IDataMiner dataMiner)
    {
        _logger = logger ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(logger));
        _options = options?.Value ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(options));
        _healthCheck = healthCheck ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(healthCheck));
        _migrationTool = migrationTool ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(migrationTool));
        _dataMiner = dataMiner ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(dataMiner));
        _configuration = configuration ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(configuration));
        _notificationService = notificationService ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(notificationService));
    }

    [Singleton]
    [FunctionName("MigrateDatabase")]
    public IActionResult MigrateDatabase([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get")]
        HttpRequest req)
    {
        string responseMsg;
        var connString = _configuration.GetConnectionString(MarketListingDbContext.ConnectionStringName);
        _logger.LogInformation($"HTTP trigger function MigrateDatabase connection string: {connString}");

        try
        {
            _migrationTool.Migrate();
            responseMsg = "Success";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex, ex.Message);
            return new BadRequestErrorMessageResult(ex.Message);
        }

        return new OkObjectResult(responseMsg);
    }

    [FunctionName("Heartbeat")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Heartbeat(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = "heartbeat")]
        HttpRequest request)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation($"Received heartbeat request\nsettings:\n{_options.ToJson()}");
        var status = await _healthCheck.CheckHealthAsync();

        return new OkObjectResult(Enum.GetName(typeof(HealthStatus), status.Status));
    }
    
    [Singleton]
    [FunctionName("MarketListingReport")]
    public async Task Report([TimerTrigger("%GenerateReportSchedule%", RunOnStartup = true)] TimerInfo timer)
    {
        try
        {
            _logger.LogInformation($"Generating data ingestion report:\n{_options.TeamsConfiguration.ToJsonDebug()}");
            await _notificationService.SendNotificationAsync(_options.TeamsConfiguration);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex.Message);
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The issue is that _One of the request inputs is out of range_. The function might be trying to access a non-existent (or no longer existing) resource. Could you show us some (relevant) code so we can see what the issue could be?

Comment: @rickvdbosch I've added code. Essentially I have 3 functions now.

Comment: Which one is the Function causing the error? Because of all the classes that hide the implementation, based on this information it's almost impossible for us to help you.

Comment: I removed everything, created a brand new FunctionApp from VS2019 template. Still getting the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem might be with case sensitivity, since ...

- All letters in a container name must be lowercase.
- Blob names are case-sensitive.

Check your Function's settings to make sure your connection string, container name and blob names are correct and you don't have any glitches on those.

For a full overview of the rules, see [Naming and Referencing Containers, Blobs, and Metadata](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/Naming-and-Referencing-Containers--Blobs--and-Metadata).

Comment: this led me to check the configuration. Turns out we had Capitalized AccountName=DevDataMiner" instead of "devdataminer" under "AzureWebJobsStorage"